# How can I add a variable in a code block in a Discord message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How can I write a code block (using the discord.js library) in a Discord message like this:

[image: Message image]

I am trying with the variable `num`, but it still gets recognized as text and doesn't get replaced with the actual value

````js
.addField("```change ${num}```");
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image you put is not an embed, it's just a message where someone has been mentioned, and so it's yellow.

To make a code block in Discord you have to type a normal message like this:

````
```
your code text here
```
````

Discord will then use markdown to display it as a code block. For further help on Discord markdown, please see [this article](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/210298617-Markdown-Text-101-Chat-Formatting-Bold-Italic-Underline-).

If you're trying to use that `num` variable inside a string, you should start and end that string with backticks (`). Please note that if you want to put other backticks in the string you have to escape them with a backward slash (`\`).
Here's an example:

```
`\`\`\`\nYour text: ${num}\n\`\`\``
```

You can always append the variable with a plus `+` operator:

````js
"```\nYour text: " + num + "\n```"
````

Comment: Hi Federico, thank you very much, your answer helped me a lot 
Now it works perfectly :D!

Comment: Happy to hear that :)