# Discord.js Bot mentioning Voice Channels

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots, message

I have a specific event (voiceStateUpdate) that has to mention sometimes a Voice Channel:

```
            channel.send(`The Channel is:`+"``"+`<#${newMember.channelID}>`+"``");
```

As one can see, I want that the channel is being mentioned with those `` around them, so the channel in Discord is in this black box. But my actual output looks like this:

The Channel is: `<#1234134234134>`

So in Discord this Black Box works, but the Channel is displayed not with its name, but with the ID

Comment: That's not an answer on the SO's question @Toasty

Comment: I've reproduced your issue and I think Discord simply doesn't allow that. It just works if you start with two ``, then enter the channel <#CHANNELID> and then close it. https://i.imgur.com/eFm9Vya.gif

Comment: You can't put a mention around "``"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the right result, you simply imitate Discord's conversion of the format <#CHANNELID>.

```
channel.send(`The Channel is:`+"`"+`${newMember.channel.name}`+"`");
```

This will get the exact same result, as if one would post as a user the message with Discord's conversion form

Answer (score 0):

<s>Try it this way:</s>

```
channel.send('`' + `The Channel is: <#${newMember.channelId}>` + '`');
```

For a single line [code block](https://gist.github.com/matthewzring/9f7bbfd102003963f9be7dbcf7d40e51#code-blocks) you only need to wrap it in grave accents once.

**Edit:**

[grafpatron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67004927/13685706) is the correct one

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54110493/how-can-i-add-a-variable-in-a-code-block-in-a-discord-message/54113393) fix your problem?